# Prob. 14, Sec. 2.7, in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis Book: How to find the norm of this bounded linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A \colon = \left[\alpha_{ij} \right]_{m\times n}$ be a given $m \times n$ matrix of real numbers.

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the normed space of all the ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers with the norm defined as follows:
$$
\lVert x \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n} \colon= \sum_{j=1}^n \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert  \qquad \forall x \colon= \left(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Let $\mathbb{R}^m$ be the normed space of all the ordered $m$-tuples of real numbers with the norm defined as follows:
$$ 
\lVert y \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^m} \colon= \sum_{i=1}^m \left\lvert \eta_i \right\rvert  \ \ \ \forall y \colon= \left(\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_m \right) \in \mathbb{R}^m.$$

Let the operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be defined as
$$
T(x) \colon= Ax \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n;$$
where $x$ is to be written as a column vector and $Ax$ denotes the usual matrix product. Of course, $T$ is linear.

What is $\lVert T \rVert$?

Here we are using the following definition for $\lVert T \rVert$:
$$
\lVert T \rVert \colon= \sup \left\{  \frac{\lVert T(x)\rvert_{\mathbb{R}^m}}{\lVert x \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}} \colon  x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \neq \mathbf{0}_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \right\}. $$

My effort:

For any $x \colon= (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n ) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert T(x) \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^m} 
&=  \sum_{i=1}^m \left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} \xi_j \right\rvert  \\ 
& \leq  \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \left\lvert \alpha_{ij} \xi_j \right\rvert \right) \\ 
&=  \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n  \left( \left\lvert \alpha_{ij} \right\rvert   \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert \right) \right) \\ 
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left( \left\lvert \alpha_{ij} \right\rvert   \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert \right) \right) \\ 
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ij} \right\rvert  \right) \right) \\ 
&\leq  \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert  \max_{k= 1, \ldots, n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ik} \right\rvert  \right) \right) \\ 
&=  \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \left\lvert \xi_j \right\rvert  \right) \max_{k= 1, \ldots, n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ik} \right\rvert  \right) \\ 
&= \lVert x \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n} \max_{k= 1, \ldots, n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ik} \right\rvert  \right). 
\end{align}
$$
If $x$ is not the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  then upon dividing by the norm of $x$ and then taking the supremum of the quantity on the left hand side, we obtain
$$\lVert T \rVert \leq \max_{k= 1, \ldots, n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ik} \right\rvert  \right). $$

Is it true that
$$\lVert T \rVert = \max_{k= 1, \ldots, n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m  \left\lvert \alpha_{ik} \right\rvert  \right)?$$
If so, then how to show this?

Comment: What if you let $x = e_i = (0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ where the 1 occurs at the $i$-th position?

Comment: @M.B. fantastic idea!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the maximum $\max_{k=1,\ldots,n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|\alpha_{ik}| = M$(say) is attained for $ k = k_0$, i.e, $M = \sum_{i=1}^{m}|\alpha_{ik_0}|$. Then take the vector $x= (0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ with $1$ at the $k_0$ position. Notice that $\|Tx\|_{\mathbb{R^m}} = M$. Since there is a vector such that this supremum is attained, it follows that $\|T\| = M$.

Comment: Indeed!! Thanks very much.

Comment: Never Mind...Happy to Help!!!